# Colorbox Disabled after opening New pop up from Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, colorbox

I have a colorbox and in that some field with submit button.
I want to open pop up page after inserting data on database like this :

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext m = new DataClasses1DataContext(GetConnectionString.GetCS(Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDLogined"]))))
 {
            m.TblCarTakhalofShakhsiFishes.InsertOnSubmit(new TblCarTakhalofShakhsiFish
            {
                IdTakhalofShakhshi = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["abuseid"]),
                OvnanFish = txtOnvan.Text
            });
            m.SubmitChanges();


   int _idabuse = m.TblCarTakhalofShakhsiFishes.ToArray().Last().Id;


string _redirect = "../Parvande/PreviewTakhalof.aspx?abuseid=" +_idabuse.ToString();

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenPDFScript", "window.open('" + _redirect + "');", true);
 }
```

It works fine , but after opening pop up window , my colorbox will disable , for example close button doesn't work and it not close .
what is problem?

Comment: are you using update panel and java script colorbox?

Comment: @Amit i don't use updatepanel , my page which is in colorbox postback after submitting.